# react js-× TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an issue with this code:
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Please guide me on what to do

app.js

```
import React from "react";

import {CardList} from "./componets/card-list/card-list";


class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state={
            monsters:
                []
        };
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then((data) => {
                this.setState({ monsters: data })
            })
    }
    render() {
     return(
         <div>
             <CardList monters={this.state.monsters}/>
         </div>
     )
 }
}
export default App;
```

and cardlist.jsx
Please guide me on what to do

````
import './card-list.css'


export const CardList=(props) => (

     <div className='card-list'>{props.monsters.map(monster =>(<h1 key={monster.id}>{monster.name}</h1>))}

    </div>
);```
````

Comment: `monters` !== `monsters`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed here:

```
<CardList monters={this.state.monsters}/>
```

You called your prop `monters`

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the default value of data to empty array incase you receive nothing from the fetch request. Try following:

```js
import React from "react";

import {CardList} from "./componets/card-list/card-list";


class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state={
            monsters:
                []
        };
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then((data = []) => {
                this.setState({ monsters: data })
            })
    }
    render() {
     return(
         <div>
             <CardList monters={this.state.monsters}/>
         </div>
     )
 }
}
export default App;
```